# Add files one by one into my ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I have `ListView` that i want to populate.
All i want to do is to get my `List` with all the items and add this into my `ListView` but i want it to be gradually.

My `List`

```
Dictionary<string, double> collection;
```

Model:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public DataTable PieData { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.PieData = GetTestData();
    }

    private static DataTable GetTestData()
    {
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable("DATA");

        dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(double)));
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in collection)
            dtData.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.Key, item.Value });

        return dtData;
    }
}
```

My timer:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;

public void CreateTimer()
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
}
```

Add into my `ListView` via my Timer:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in collection)
        ipStatisticsListView.Items.Add(new MyItem { IP = item.Key, Percent = item.Value });
}
```

Currently what happening is that although i declare 100 milliseconds between every add operation i have half second of delay and than i can see all my list inside my `LisView`

Comment: As far as I can tell, this adds *all* the items to the listview every 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

I dictionary must be a list if a key can contain more than one value.  So use one of the methods below.  the dictionary doesn't make a copy of the Values to there are links between the dictionary to the row values in the datatable.

```
            DataTable dtData = new DataTable("DATA");
            Dictionary<string, List<double>> collection1 = dtData.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"), y => y.Field<double>("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            Dictionary<string, double> collection2 = dtData.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"), y => y.Field<double>("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
​
```

Comment: What i need to do with collection1 or collection2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because when a new item is added into the `ListView` control, there's an invalidate event which causes the control to redraw itself. If the frequency between items being added is too low, the addition of a new item may cause the control to invalidate itself again, and therefore "suspend" drawing the list.

Perhaps when the `ListView` reaches the maximum number of items visible within content bounds, it no longer needs to re-draw itself whenever a new item is added, thus it can paint itself.

Have you tried increasing the interval between timer ticks to see whether the same issue occurs?

Comment: Yes i even try 500 milliseconds